# Function inheritance and return types in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I'm learning C++ and I came across a problem that I can tackle with my previous programming experience (mainly C and Java; some but limited OOP experience), but I'd like to know what would be a proper, modern C++ solution to it. The problem concerns inheritance and derived classes' versions of a virtual function with different return types. Based on multiple Stack Overflow threads such a thing isn't possible. So how should I go about the following?

To practice C++ features, I'm writing a ray tracer. I have a virtual base class `Object` and derived classes `Polyhedron` and `Polygon` to describe the objects `Ray`s of light can interact with. (In reality I have intermediate virtual classes `Solid` and `Face,` and derived classes `Sphere`, `Cylinder`, `Circle` alongside `Polyhedron` and `Polygon`, but let's forget about them here to keep things simple.) Currently, I've only implemented emission and absorption of light, i.e., a `Ray` only goes straight without any refraction or reflections. Absorption within a `Polyhedron` is proportional to intensity (exponential decay), so I have to figure out the objects a `Ray` passes through and integrate the `Ray`'s intensity forward from its source to where it hits the detector. I have a vector `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Intersection>> intersections` to store all these intersections of a `Ray` with the objects in a simulated scene. An intersection needs to contain the intersection `Point`s, the intersected `Polygon` faces and the `Polyhedron` itself for a `Polyhedron` object, or alternatively the intersection `Point` and the `Polygon` face itself for a `Polygon` object. Consequently, I'd like to have derived classes `Intersection_Polyhedron` and `Intersection_Polygon` to override the call to `Intersection::modulate_intensity(const double intensity_before) const` which is supposed to return a `Ray`'s intensity after passing the object in question. In other words, I'd like to avoid checking the type of the intersected objects and instead take advantage of inheritance when calculating the modulation to a `Ray`'s intensity.

I would like to have each `Ray` simply loop through a vector `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects` containing all the objects in a simulated scene, call the virtual function `Object::get_intersection(const Ray& ray) const` and get either `Intersection_Polyhedron` or `Intersection_Polygon` in return based on the type of the intersection (if it's with a `Polyhedron` or a `Polygon`). Pointers to these derived intersection objects would be pushed back into `intersections`, `intersections` would be sorted based on the distance from the `Ray`'s origin and then looped through to call and override `Intersection::modulate_intensity()` to determine a `Ray`'s final intensity on the detector. To me, this would sound like the C++/OOP way of achieving this, but it doesn't seem possible because derived classes' versions of a base class's virtual function must all have the same return type. So how should I do it?

(Currently, I return a singular type of `Intersection` from `get_intersection()` for both `Polyhedrons` and `Polygons`. As its members, an `Intersection` has vectors for intersection `Points` and intersected `std::shared_ptr<Polygon>` faces, and an `std::shared_ptr<Polyhedron>` (which is a `nullptr` for `Polygon`s as there's no bulk). To distinguish between intersections of `Polyhedrons` and `Polygons`, I simpy check if there are one or two intersection `Points`. This isn't too inelegant, but modern C++ has to offer a better way of achieving this with inheritance, right?)

Some very C++-like pseudocode to further clarify what I'd like to achieve:

```
// ...

// create objects in a scene
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
// ...

// find a ray's intersections with the objects
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Intersection>> intersections;
for(const auto& object : objects) {
  // virtual class Object's function overridden with that of Polyhedron or Polygon
  // returns std::shared_ptr<Intersection_Polyhedron> or std::shared_ptr<Intersection_Polygon> based on type of object
  auto intersection = object->get_intersection(ray);
  intersections.push_back(intersection);
}

// sort the intersections with std::sort and a lambda expression
// ...

// calculate a ray's intensity
double intensity = 0.0;
for(const auto& intersection : intersections) {
  // virtual class Intersection's function overridden with that of Intensity_Polyhedron or Intensity_Polygon
  intensity = intersection->modulate_intensity(intensity);
}

// ...
```

Comment: As `Intersection` is base class of `Intersection_Polyhedron` and `Intersection_Polygon`, both `object->get_intersection(ray)` can return `std::shared_ptr<Intersection>` for the virtual method...

Comment: Are you implying `Polyhedron::get_intersection()` would construct an `Intersection_Polyhedron` but return an `std::shared_ptr<Intersection>` to it, and `Polygon::get_intersection()` would construct an `Intersection_Polygon` but also return an `std::shared_ptr<Intersection>` to it? Then when `intersection->modulate_intensity()` is called, it's overridden by either `Intersection_Polyhedron::modulate_intensity()` or `Intersection_Polygon::modulate_intensity()` as appropriate. I wonder why I didn't come to think of this. I guess these new inheritance and smart pointer things had melted my brain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning interface is fine in general:

```
class Ray;

struct Intersection
{
    virtual ~Intersection() = default;
    virtual double modulate_intensity(double intensity) = 0;
};
struct Intersection_Polygon : Intersection
{
    double modulate_intensity(double intensity) override {/**/}
};
struct Intersection_Polyhedron : Intersection
{
    double modulate_intensity(double intensity) override {/**/}
};

struct Object
{
    virtual ~Object() = default;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Intersection> get_intersection(const Ray&) = 0;
};

struct Polygon : Object
{
    std::shared_ptr<Intersection> get_intersection(const Ray&) override {
        return std::make_shared<Intersection_Polygon>();
    }
};
struct Polyhedron : Object
{
    std::shared_ptr<Intersection> get_intersection(const Ray&) override {
        return std::make_shared<Intersection_Polyhedron>();
    }
};
```

Return type can be improved with covariance, but C++ only handle it for references and (non-smart) pointers. So it requires some boiler plate to simulate it for smart pointers:

```
struct Object
{
    virtual ~Object() = default;
    std::shared_ptr<Intersection> get_intersection(const Ray& ray)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Intersection>{get_intersection_ptr(ray)};
    }
protected:
    virtual Intersection* get_intersection_ptr(const Ray&) = 0;
};

struct Polygon : Object
{
    std::shared_ptr<Intersection_Polygon> get_intersection(const Ray& ray)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Intersection_Polygon>{get_intersection_ptr(ray)};
    }
protected:
    Intersection_Polygon* get_intersection_ptr(const Ray&) override {
        return new Intersection_Polygon();
    }
};
```

template (possibly CRTP) might help to factorize boiler plate:

```
template <typename IntersectionType>
struct ObjectT : Object
{
    std::shared_ptr<IntersectionType> get_intersection(const Ray& ray)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<IntersectionType>{get_intersection_ptr(ray)};
    }
protected:
    IntersectionType* get_intersection_ptr(const Ray&) override {
        return new IntersectionType();
    }
};

struct Polygon : ObjectT<Intersection_Polygon> {};
struct Polyhedron : ObjectT<Intersection_Polyhedron> {};
```

Comment: Thank you for reading my lengthy question and providing such a clear answer. The first part of your solution seems to work well and I'll try the covariance and template improvements after some more digesting.